# Check string in 2d array

Tags: java

I got a 2d array from a .tsv file, and i have done this to it

The file have information content somewhat like:

```
HG  sn  FA  
PC  2   16:0
PI  1   18:0
PS  3   20:0
PE  2   24:0
        26:0
        16:1
        18:2

String[][] root;

List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("table.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

lines.removeAll(Arrays.asList("", null));  

root = new String[lines.size()][]; 

for(int i =0; i<lines.size(); i++){
root[i] = lines.get(i).split("\t");
```

Then a user input can be put in, which is then split into strings

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );
 System.out.print("Input =>");
 String lipid = sc.nextLine();


 String parts[] = lipid.split(" ");
 String hg = parts[0];
 String lc = parts [1];
```

This user input could be something like PC 34:2, i then want to check the string hg in the 2darray, to find information about the sn value. This value shall later be used in a mathematical algorithm.

But how do i check the string hg in the 2d array, to get information of sn values?

Comment: Please use proper code indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String result = null;

for(int i=0;i<root.length;i++){

    if(root[i][0].equals(hg)){
         result = root[i][1];
         break;
    }
}

System.out.println("result=" + result);
```

Comment: String sn = null; i get error that varialbe sn is defined as string[]  and i get the error cannot find symbol method size()

Answer (score 0):

You can do simple search by running a **for loop** on root and check for **root[i][0].equals(hg);**

If yes **return root[i][1];**

**[UPDATE]**
Code for the same:

```
String sn;

for(int i = 0; i < root.length; i++) {

    if (root[i][0].equals(hg)) { // check for matching value of 'hg' in first column
        sn = root[i][1]; // corresponding 'sn' value from 2D array
        break;
    }
}

// to extract double value from string sn
double sn_value = -1;

if (sn != null) { 
    sn_value = Double.valueOf(sn);
}
```

Also read about `HashMap` and `HashTable` (based on KEY-VALUE retrieval), will be helpful in future.

Cheers,

Mitesh

Comment: i am not quite sure how that for loop should be build, and how the values would be returned?

Comment: ^^In java its easy to play with objects; so what I recommend is to follow @Svettin's answer.... clean-simple yet powerful code